# Angularjs reload values in LocalStorage variable when I come back to view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angular-local-storage

I have a view that use a LocalStorage Object Variable (called Entity).

```
/* Entity Service */ 
.factory('EntityService', function (){  
  return {
    getEntity : function(){
      return JSON.parse(window.localStorage['entity'] || false);
    }
  };
})

/* Route definition */
.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
  controller: 'AppCtrl',
  resolve : {
    Entity : function(EntityService){
      return EntityService.getEntity();
    }
  }
})

/* AppCtrl*/
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,Entity) {
  $scope.model = {
   entity : Entity
  };
})

/* AppCtrl (view) */    
<ion-view view-title="{{ model.entity.name }}">
    <ion-content>
        <div class="padding">Home</div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>

/* EntitiesCtrl */
$scope.setEntity = function(entity){
  window.localStorage['entity'] = JSON.stringify(entity);
  $state.go('app.home');
}

/* EntitiesCtrl (view)*/
<div class="list">      
  <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="setEntity(entity)" ng-repeat="entity in model.entities">
    <img src="img/entities/{{ entity.logo }}">
    <h2>{{ entity.name }} - {{ entity.acronym }}</h2>
    <p>{{ entity.city.name }} - {{ entity.city.state.acronym }}</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

The value of LocalStorage variable *entity* is changed in the EntitiesCtrl, but when the $state.go('app.home') show the Home view, the value wasn't changed in the

```
{{ model.entity.name }}
```

What can I do to take new value of **window.localStorage['entity']** every time the *$state.go('app.home');* is called?

Thanks!

Comment: A quick thought - you could trigger via a directive in the view.  Probably not the cleanest solution, but that should work.

Comment: I don't see how I can do this, because <ion-view> is already a directive. I'm just a beginner in Angularjs. Can you explain better?

Comment: Directives can be nested.  And nested directives without a scope access the scope of their parent.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the service so it returns reference to an object. Then any changes made in any controller should update that same object prior to storing back in localStorage. You would then have prototypical inheritance binding across the app

```
.factory('EntityService', function (){
  var entity;  
  return {
    getEntity : function(){
      if(!entity){
          entity = JSON.parse(window.localStorage['entity'] || false);
       }
      return entity;// object stored in service now
    },
     saveEntity:function(){
         if(entity){
           window.localStorage['entity'] = JSON.stringify(entity);
        }                   
     }
  };
});
```

Then instead of updating localStorage directly, update the object and use save method in service

Comment: My version of Ionic was v1.0.0-rc.1 and your solution does not work. I updated the version of the Ionic to v1.0.0-rc.5 and now it works. See [codepen example](http://codepen.io/leoalmar/pen/ZGGOEb). Thanks @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `view-title="{{ model.entity.name }}">`, try:

```
<ion-nav-title>{{model.entity.name}}</ion-nav-title>
```

I am not sure `viewTitle` supports angular interpolations.